# PLSQL - exception in a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

Use exception in a procedure.

Procedure for insert into statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pSaveProductGroup (p_parentCode VARCHAR2, p_nameGroup VARCHAR2) IS

v_var "ProductGroups"."code"%type;
BEGIN

select p."code" into v_var
from "ProductGroups" p
where p."code"=p_parentCode;

if v_var is not null then

INSERT INTO "ProductGroups"
("parentCode","nameGroup")
VALUES(p_parentCode,p_nameGroup);
end if;

EXCEPTION
WHEN v_var is null then
dbms_output.put_line('Undefined group.');

END;
```

It should print exception when needed.

```
Error: Error(18,12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following:     . then or
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to catch the exception.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pSaveProductGroup (p_parentCode    VARCHAR2,
                                               p_nameGroup     VARCHAR2)
IS
   v_var   "ProductGroups"."code"%TYPE;
   myex    EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (myex, -20016);
BEGIN
   SELECT p."code"
     INTO v_var
     FROM "ProductGroups" p
    WHERE p."code" = p_parentCode;

   IF v_var IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      INSERT INTO "ProductGroups" ("parentCode", "nameGroup")
           VALUES (p_parentCode, p_nameGroup);
   ELSE
      IF (v_var IS NULL)
      THEN
         RAISE myex;
      END IF;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN myex
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'ERROR_STACK: "Undefined group --> ' || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack);
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'ERROR_STACK: NO_DATA_FOUND --> ' || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack);
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'ERROR_STACK: OTHERS --> ' || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack);
END;
```

The modified version of the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pSaveProductGroup (p_parentCode    VARCHAR2,
                                               p_nameGroup     VARCHAR2)
IS
   v_var   "ProductGroups"."code"%TYPE;
   myex    EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (myex, -20016);
BEGIN
   SELECT p."code"
     INTO v_var
     FROM "ProductGroups" p
    WHERE p."code" = p_parentCode;

   IF v_var IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      INSERT INTO "ProductGroups" ("parentCode", "nameGroup")
           VALUES (p_parentCode, p_nameGroup);
   ELSE
      RAISE myex;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN myex
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'ERROR_STACK: Undefined group --> ' || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack);
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'ERROR_STACK: NO_DATA_FOUND --> ' || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack);
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'ERROR_STACK: OTHERS --> ' || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack);
END;
```

Comment: When I call this procedure: set serveroutput on
begin
pSaveProductGroup('G5','Group 13');
end; it doesn't print exception. It prints 01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.

Comment: @user10966491 I have updated my answer, re-execute the procedure to find out the error details. I doubt your select statement does not return any rows.

Comment: But I want to print "Undefined group" when exception is raised. How to do that?

Comment: @user10966491  `IF (v_var IS NULL)` This statement should execute to `RAISE Undefined group` exception. Correct me if I am wrong. The point is there are other errors in the procedure which is preventing the execution to catch your `Undefined group`. First you need to find out which error line is having `NO_DATA_FOUND`

Comment: @user10966491 `DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack` will provide more insight about the error.